# Не расшифровывает JsonWebToken

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Хотел сделать чтобы некоторые ветки API сервера на node+express имели защиту токеном и были доступны только авторизованым пользователем но постоянно получаю

```
{
    "message": "auth failed"
}
```

Вот код проверки токена:

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
        console.log(token)
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'shh')
        console.log(decoded)
        req.userData = decoded
        next()  
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'auth failed'
        })
    }
}
```

`console.log(token)` выводит нормально токен а вот `console.log(decoded)` ничего не выводит и поэтому мне кажется что проблема в нем но я смотрю как в документации [jsonwevtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) так и у меня.Так в чем проблема?

Код в котором идет проверка:

```
router.post('/',checkAuth,upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        productImage: req.file.path
    })
    product.save()
        .then((result) => {
            res.status(201).json({
                createdProduct: result
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
})
```

Ошибка

```
{ JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:122:19
    at getSecret (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:76:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:80:10)
    at module.exports (X:\projects\Brand-server\src\middleware\check-auth.js:7:23)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at X:\projects\Brand-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' }
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018:18:43:21 +0000] "POST /products HTTP/1.1" 401 25 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.5"
```

Comment: Ну так вы посмотрите содержимое `error`, в нём ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Обвновил вопрос.Все равно не понял что значит не верная сигнатура?Я же сделал как в документации)

Comment: Очевидно jwt.verify считает ваш токен невалидным

Comment: Спасибо)Исправил

Answer (score 1):

Срок действия токена был истек))Нужно было заново залогинится и тогда создался новый токен и все заработало.